# java - cycle through time for a day

Tags: java

I need to iterate throught the time for one day.
I have the starting time: `00:00` and the end time: `23:59`.
I want to cycle through every minute of an hour.

How can I achieve this in Java? Does any Java library for this exist?

Comment: do you need it to be a date object or just display the numbers?

Comment: just hour and time. no date object.
should be like :9:00, 9:01,9:02...10:00,10:01..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int hour = 0; hour <= 23; hour++) {
    for (int minute = 0; minute <= 59; minute++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No. You'd normally be right to be suspicious of nested loops - they will tend to operate in O(n^x) time, where x is the number of times the loop is nested.

With this case, however, there are always exactly 1440 iterations. Whether you express that as a single loop that repeats 1440 times or a loop that calls a loop that repeats 60 times 24 times (60 * 24 = 1440), you will perform 1440 actions. Thus, using two loops is a perfectly reasonable - and more readable - implementation. A good optimising compiler would likely unroll both implementations and you'd end up with identical machine code.

Comment: No more looping than in Garee's code, just split into hours and minutes

Comment: 24 * 60 = 1440 iterations, and there is 1440 minutes in a day. If you want to iterate over all minutes of a day, I'm afraid there isn't much more options.

Comment: Also, in this case, two nested loops are more efficient than a single loop doing some computation to obtain hour and minute numbers. You don't have to play with modulo and divisions (as in Matti's code, for example).

Answer (score 1):

JODA is nice for date and time manipulation.  You might find the LocalTime class interesting:  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#LocalTime(int, int)

Answer (score 1):

1 hour is 60 minutes.
60 minutes x 24 hours = 1440 minutes per day.

```
int minutes;  
for ( minutes = 1440 ; minutes > 0; minutes-- ) //  00:00 - 23:59
{
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and separates the data and format:

```
for(int minutes = 0; minutes < 1440; minutes++) //1440 = 24 * 60
    System.out.println(String.format("%d:%2d", minutes/60, minutes%60));
```

If you want to comma delimit as you showed above you could join the result of a custom anonymous iterator or do this:

```
for(int minutes = 0; minutes < 1440; minutes++) //1440 = 24 * 60
    System.out.print(String.format("%d:%2d%s", minutes/60, minutes%60, minutes<1439?", ":""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the minutes of each hour and hour of a day with a simple loop and modulo

```
while hour < 24:
    mins = (mins + 1) % 60
    hour += mins == 0 ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: That's a strange form of Java.